# suggestion for improving my long python code with a shorter and correct version

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling

As a part of an online exercise, I want to Write a function, persistence, that takes in a positive parameter num and returns its 
multiplicative persistence, which is the number of times you must multiply the digits in num until you reach a single digit.
For example:

persistence(39) => 3  # Because 3*9 = 27, 2*7 = 14, 1*4=4
                       # and 4 has only one digit.

persistence(999) => 4 # Because 9*9*9 = 729, 7*2*9 = 126,
                       # 1*2*6 = 12, and finally 1*2 = 2.

persistence(4) => 0   # Because 4 is already a one-digit number.

This is my code:

```
def persistence(n):
    count=0
    if n<10:
        return(count)
    else:
        count+=1
        a=([int(d) for d in str(n)])
        result = 1
        for i in a:
            result=result*i
        if result<10:
            return(count)
        else:
            count+=1
            a=([int(d) for d in str(result)])
            result1 = 1
            for i in a:
                result1=result1*i
                if result1<10:
                    return(count)
                else:
                    count+=1
                    a=([int(d) for d in str(result1)])
                    result2=1
                    for i in a:
                        result2=result2*i
                        if result2<10:
                            return(count)
                        else:
                            count+=1
                            a=([int(d) for d in str(result1)])
                            result3=1
                            for i in a:
                                result3=result3*i
                                if result3<10:
                                    return(count)
```

but when I try n=999 it gives me 2 which is incorrect. Also it is limited to only 4 multiplicative persistence. How can I improve this code. Tnx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work because you don't know how many times you need to perform the operation to get a single digit number. What you can do in this situation is create a loop and let it run as long as the number is greater than 10. You can try something like this:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

def persistence(n):
    count = 0
    while n >= 10:
        n = reduce(mul, map(int, str(n)))
        count += 1
    return count
```

And the reason why it does not work for 999 is because the `if` statement in the second `for` loop. You are checking if `result1` is smaller than 10 **inside** the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I found this short answer as well:

```
import operator
def persistence(n):
    i = 0
    while n>=10:
        n=reduce(operator.mul,[int(x) for x in str(n)],1)
        i+=1
    return i
```